# TypeError: 'Welcome3' object is not subscriptable JSON

Tags: python, json

I want to convert a string from Json to python strings and output them to the console. To do this, I use the site https://codebeautify.org/json-to-python-pojo-generator .

This is my JSON string:

```
{"success":true,"data":[{"contract":"atomicassets","collection_name":"happyfields1","name":"Trippy Fields","img":"QmbCfnAii5xAeQGXB6pFk5VqygqTRUSZgWfw3nq9Yh1hoD","author":"kz23o.c.wam","allow_notify":true,"authorized_accounts":["kz23o.c.wam"],"notify_accounts":[],"market_fee":0.04,"data":{"img":"QmbCfnAii5xAeQGXB6pFk5VqygqTRUSZgWfw3nq9Yh1hoD","url":"https://wax.atomichub.io/trading/link/1660511?key=5JPUNm6mknfk1s1GxV3PgYp2UcdpWaNVTbZaR8pB9tMjgHCDBx2","name":"Trippy Fields","images":"{\"banner_1920x500\":\"QmY2Xp1A6fknv8j35tG9uTJ2SBQZNEZJeQx4cxpLKdB6fs\",\"logo_512x512\":\"QmbCfnAii5xAeQGXB6pFk5VqygqTRUSZgWfw3nq9Yh1hoD\"}","socials":"{\"twitter\":\"\",\"medium\":\"\",\"facebook\":\"\",\"github\":\"\",\"discord\":\"https://discord.gg/VEPbyn8c\",\"youtube\":\"\",\"telegram\":\"\"}","creator_info":"{\"country\":\"\",\"address\":\"\",\"city\":\"\",\"zip\":\"\",\"company\":\"\",\"name\":\"\",\"registration_number\":\"\"}"},"created_at_time":"1668703931500","created_at_block":"214480753"}],"query_time":1668712130560}
```

And this is the code from the site I use for this:

```
from typing import Any, List, TypeVar, Callable, Type, cast


T = TypeVar("T")


def from_str(x: Any) -> str:
    assert isinstance(x, str)
    return x


def from_bool(x: Any) -> bool:
    assert isinstance(x, bool)
    return x


def from_list(f: Callable[[Any], T], x: Any) -> List[T]:
    assert isinstance(x, list)
    return [f(y) for y in x]


def from_float(x: Any) -> float:
    assert isinstance(x, (float, int)) and not isinstance(x, bool)
    return float(x)


def to_float(x: Any) -> float:
    assert isinstance(x, float)
    return x


def to_class(c: Type[T], x: Any) -> dict:
    assert isinstance(x, c)
    return cast(Any, x).to_dict()


def from_int(x: Any) -> int:
    assert isinstance(x, int) and not isinstance(x, bool)
    return x


class Data:
    img: str
    url: str
    name: str
    images: str
    socials: str
    creator_info: str

    def __init__(self, img: str, url: str, name: str, images: str, socials: str, creator_info: str) -> None:
        self.img = img
        self.url = url
        self.name = name
        self.images = images
        self.socials = socials
        self.creator_info = creator_info

    @staticmethod
    def from_dict(obj: Any) -> 'Data':
        assert isinstance(obj, dict)
        img = from_str(obj.get("img"))
        url = from_str(obj.get("url"))
        name = from_str(obj.get("name"))
        images = from_str(obj.get("images"))
        socials = from_str(obj.get("socials"))
        creator_info = from_str(obj.get("creator_info"))
        return Data(img, url, name, images, socials, creator_info)

    def to_dict(self) -> dict:
        result: dict = {}
        result["img"] = from_str(self.img)
        result["url"] = from_str(self.url)
        result["name"] = from_str(self.name)
        result["images"] = from_str(self.images)
        result["socials"] = from_str(self.socials)
        result["creator_info"] = from_str(self.creator_info)
        return result


class Datum:
    contract: str
    collection_name: str
    name: str
    img: str
    author: str
    allow_notify: bool
    authorized_accounts: List[str]
    notify_accounts: List[Any]
    market_fee: float
    data: Data
    created_at_time: str
    created_at_block: int

    def __init__(self, contract: str, collection_name: str, name: str, img: str, author: str, allow_notify: bool, authorized_accounts: List[str], notify_accounts: List[Any], market_fee: float, data: Data, created_at_time: str, created_at_block: int) -> None:
        self.contract = contract
        self.collection_name = collection_name
        self.name = name
        self.img = img
        self.author = author
        self.allow_notify = allow_notify
        self.authorized_accounts = authorized_accounts
        self.notify_accounts = notify_accounts
        self.market_fee = market_fee
        self.data = data
        self.created_at_time = created_at_time
        self.created_at_block = created_at_block

    @staticmethod
    def from_dict(obj: Any) -> 'Datum':
        assert isinstance(obj, dict)
        contract = from_str(obj.get("contract"))
        collection_name = from_str(obj.get("collection_name"))
        name = from_str(obj.get("name"))
        img = from_str(obj.get("img"))
        author = from_str(obj.get("author"))
        allow_notify = from_bool(obj.get("allow_notify"))
        authorized_accounts = from_list(from_str, obj.get("authorized_accounts"))
        notify_accounts = from_list(lambda x: x, obj.get("notify_accounts"))
        market_fee = from_float(obj.get("market_fee"))
        data = Data.from_dict(obj.get("data"))
        created_at_time = from_str(obj.get("created_at_time"))
        created_at_block = int(from_str(obj.get("created_at_block")))
        return Datum(contract, collection_name, name, img, author, allow_notify, authorized_accounts, notify_accounts, market_fee, data, created_at_time, created_at_block)

    def to_dict(self) -> dict:
        result: dict = {}
        result["contract"] = from_str(self.contract)
        result["collection_name"] = from_str(self.collection_name)
        result["name"] = from_str(self.name)
        result["img"] = from_str(self.img)
        result["author"] = from_str(self.author)
        result["allow_notify"] = from_bool(self.allow_notify)
        result["authorized_accounts"] = from_list(from_str, self.authorized_accounts)
        result["notify_accounts"] = from_list(lambda x: x, self.notify_accounts)
        result["market_fee"] = to_float(self.market_fee)
        result["data"] = to_class(Data, self.data)
        result["created_at_time"] = from_str(self.created_at_time)
        result["created_at_block"] = from_str(str(self.created_at_block))
        return result


class Welcome3:
    success: bool
    data: List[Datum]
    query_time: int

    def __init__(self, success: bool, data: List[Datum], query_time: int) -> None:
        self.success = success
        self.data = data
        self.query_time = query_time

    @staticmethod
    def from_dict(obj: Any) -> 'Welcome3':
        assert isinstance(obj, dict)
        success = from_bool(obj.get("success"))
        data = from_list(Datum.from_dict, obj.get("data"))
        query_time = from_int(obj.get("query_time"))
        return Welcome3(success, data, query_time)

    def to_dict(self) -> dict:
        result: dict = {}
        result["success"] = from_bool(self.success)
        result["data"] = from_list(lambda x: to_class(Datum, x), self.data)
        result["query_time"] = from_int(self.query_time)
        return result


def welcome3_from_dict(s: Any) -> Welcome3:
    return Welcome3.from_dict(s)


def welcome3_to_dict(x: Welcome3) -> Any:
    return to_class(Welcome3, x)


result = welcome3_from_dict(json.loads(a))
```

I use this line to print data, for exapmle:

```
print(result["data"])
```

What is my mistake and how can I output the variables? Thanks

Comment: What's wrong on `result = json.loads(a)["data"]`? Why so complicated?

Comment: @AndrejKesely 
`result = json.loads(a)["data"]`
`print(result["contract"])` for example
I tried this but the following error occurs: TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: the `data` section is a list, so you have to index it first. Try `print(json.loads(a)["data"][0]["contract"])`